# Remove every third element from array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static int[] replicate(int[] arr, int n) {
int[] temp = new int[arr.length];
int current=0;

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (count/n!=0){
    current = arr[i];
    count++;
    }
    if(count > 0 ){

    temp[count] = current;

    }
}

int[] whitelist = new int[count];

System.arraycopy(temp, 0, whitelist, 0, count);

return whitelist;
 }
```

I want an array that has every nth element removed. EX: If n is 3 and arr={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
The desired output would be {1,2,4,5,7}
I just can't seem to get this code to work. I know how use Lists to do this, but I want to find a way to do this without importing anything.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? What is your question?

Comment: Do you want to remove multiples of 3 or every third number?

Comment: The current code is not adding anything to the temporary array and I'm also getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions

Comment: Why do you use `if (count/n!=0)`? I suggest experimenting with `/` to check you understand what it does. I also can't see the logic behind `whitelist[0]=whitelist[1];`

Comment: Woops, didn't mean to add whitelist[0]=whitelist[1]..just edited that out. I used if (count/n!=0) because I wanted to only include elements from indices that would not be from every 3rd element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int[] replicate(int[] array, int n) {
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length - array.length / n];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != array.length; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) % n != 0) {
            newArray[j++] = array[i];
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

It creates a new array of appropriate length, iterates over all elements of the original array and copies them over to the new array only if their index is an exact multiple of n (the "+ 1" part handles the 0-based indices).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You have to do

`if (count % n != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove an element from the basic Java array. You can use various Collections and ArrayList instead.But with **commons.langs.ArrayUtils** you can preform it like below :

```
   int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) % 3 != 0) {
           arr=ArrayUtils.removeElement(arr, i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: He doesn't want to import anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `%` instead of `/` and also you don't need the second `if` statement
as you want to start storing numbers into your `temp` array from index 0 and not index 1 as your code did.

```
public static int[] replicate(int[] arr, int n) {
    int[] temp = new int[arr.length];
    int current=0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (count%n!=0){
            temp[count] = arr[i];
            count++;
        }
    }

    int[] whitelist = new int[count];

    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, whitelist, 0, count);

    return whitelist;
}
```